# How can I Link N elements with each other?

Tags: java, file-handling, custom-data-type

I want to link N elements with each other. That means element 1 will have a certain value relation with element 1, element 2, element 3 ..... element N. Similarly element 2 will have a value relationship with element 1, element 2, element 3 ... and so on. 
Also I want to store all these values inside a file(s) and modify it regularly. I prefer coding in Java.

What can be the perfect solution for this problem?

Please help me I am struck.

Comment: how can an element have a relationship with itself?

Comment: Do you want to implement some sort of Foreign Key (SQL) concept in Java? Linked list can you give you this functionality. Moreover, it seems like a school assignment to me. Show us what you have done, and we would be in better position to help you. Without that, don't expect us to give you "perfect solution".

Answer (score 0):

You have a Grid. Each element has a relationship value with each other element, ie there are (number of elements) ^ 2 relationship values.

I would use an array. Then serialize the array to save it as a file, de-serialize it to load it, edit it and then re-serialise it.

Here's some java code to save to file and back:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Grid {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // your data grid
        int num_elements=10;
        double[][] grid=new double[num_elements][num_elements];

        // populate the grid
        // note grid[m][n] holds the value for the relationship
        //  between element m and element n
        grid[0][0]=1.0;
        grid[0][1]=0.5;
        // etc...

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));

        // save the grid
        write_object(grid, "grid.data");

        // clear the grid (eg happens when you rerun your program)
        grid=null;

        // load the grid
        grid=(double[][])read_object("grid.data");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));

        // do some changes
        grid[0][0]=2.0;
        grid[0][1]=1.5;
        // etc...

        // save the grid (again)
        write_object(grid, "grid.data");

        // and so on

    }


    public static void write_object(Object no, String nfilename) {
        try {
            File f=new File(nfilename);
            if (f.exists())
                f.delete();
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(nfilename);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(no);
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Object read_object(String nfilename) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(nfilename);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Object o=ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            return o;
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```